# Scala: "Expression doesn't conform to expected type"

Tags: scala, recursion, types, pattern-matching

I'm dealing with a simple Scala program in which I defined two auxiliary functions:

```
def getInt(number: String): Int ={
  if(number=="NULL")  0
  else number.toInt
}

def getFloat(number: String): Float ={
  if(number=="NULL") 0
  else number.toFloat
}
```

And a third recursive function that call them:

```
def foldr_rating_state(l: List[(String, String, String)], sum_sat:Int, n_sat:Int, sum_ret:Float, n_ret:Int) :Float = {
  match l{
    case Nil  => ((sum_sat/n_sat)/1600)*(1-(sum_ret/n_ret)).toFloat
    case x::xs    => {
      foldr_rating_state(xs.asInstanceOf[List[(String, String, String)]],
        sum_sat+getInt(x(1)),
        n_sat+(if (getInt(x(1))==0) 0 else getInt(x(1))),
        sum_ret+getFloat(x(2)),
        n_ret+(if (getFloat(x(2))==0.toFloat) 0 else getFloat(x(2))).toInt
      )
      0.toFloat
    }
    case _ => 0.toFloat
  }
}
```

But the compiler tells me that:

- before "match l" a { is expected
- Illegal start of statement at the same point

And IntelliJ says

> Expression of type (String, String, String) doesn't conform to expected type Float

If I remove ".asInstanceOf[List[(String, String, String)]]" I get

> Type mismatch, Expected List[(String, String, String)], Actual: List[Any]

Do you have any idea about the cause of these problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First error is always most important. Further might be result of the first one. You got the syntax wrong, as compiler tells you. It is `l match { case ... }` not `match l { case ... } `

Answer (score 4):

1) Change `match l` to `l match`

2) Change `x(1)` to `x._1`  (`x` is a tuple, no a list)

Comment: @FrancescoSabiu if this solved your problem, please [mark the question as solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the fields of your tuples in a wrong way and the `l` blongs to the left of `match`. Try this

```
def foldr_rating_state(l: List[(String, String, String)], sum_sat:Int, n_sat:Int, sum_ret:Float, n_ret:Int) :Float = {
  l match {
    case Nil  => 
      ((sum_sat/n_sat)/1600)*(1-(sum_ret/n_ret)).toFloat
    case x :: xs    => {
      foldr_rating_state(
        xs,
        sum_sat+getInt(x._1),
        n_sat+(if (getInt(x._1)==0) 0 else getInt(x._1)),
        sum_ret+getFloat(x._2),
        n_ret+(if (getFloat(x._2)==0.0f) 0 else getFloat(x._2).toInt
      )
    }
    case _ => 0.0f
  }
}
```

A word about `getFloat(x._2)==0.0f`: Comparing floating point types with `==`may yield unexpected results due to a lack of precision.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So can I check it by getFloat(x._2)==0.0f ?